# Beaches in St Petersburg

Tags: russia, moscow, saint-petersburg, summer

How are beaches in St Petersburg new Finnish gulf?
Are there areas available for swimming?
Are there also sports like skiing, etc there?
I've heard also there are beaches in Moscow
How are beaches in St Petersburg in comparison with Moscow?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I want to note that the St. Petersburg is located in Neva's river delta, and only small part of it is near the Finnish Gulf. So there are two types for the beaches here:

- city beachs: most famous one is near the Petro-Pavloskaya fortress, people are getting the sun baths from February.

[image]

other ones are located accross the city parks and recreation zones, such as Krestovsky ostrov and Central Culture and Rest Park. For such beachs you can only get some rest on the sun, without swimming. Beaches are relatively small.

- outdoor beaches. Such beaches are all accross the Finnish Gulf and lakes and rivers system also known as [Vuoksi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vuoksi_River) river and lake. Such beaches are numerous and, in general, aren't clean, but wild, and this is the best fit for a company, not for the individual. One of the most popular (and most organized) is [Kavgolovo](http://lenobl.allnw.ru/db/active/kavgolovobeach) (link in Russian), but it's very crowded there.

As about the swimming, it's for certain prohibited to swim in Neva, and nearly all of the lakes and rivers are prohibited to swim into. Lakes and rivers available for swim are listed on the officials sites and some [media sites](http://tripsmile.ru/kurorty/432-gde-mozhno-kupatsja-v-sankt-peterburge-i-za-gorodom) (link in Russian). Small lakes inside the forest are, in general, safe to swim, if you are cautios and are exploring the lake before the swimming.

If you want to simply walk around the water, you can go to the [Peterhof](http://peterhofmuseum.ru/about/tour) or some other small cities near the St. Petersburg.

Comment: And what about beaches in Moscow?

Comment: @ReZa That would be an entirely different question.

Comment: @Jan I've mentioned this in my question. Comparison of Moscow and St Petersburg beaches...

Comment: Locals often prefer to swim outside of the dam area, because they believe that water quality is better outside. But that means an hour of driving from the city cetnre.

Comment: @ReZa I suggest you to create another question about the Moscow. I can't say much about it.

Comment: @zespri we do not **believe**, it's measured with medical officials

Comment: @VMAtm care to elaborate a bit on *why* the lakes and rivers are prohibited to swim into? Danger of what?

Comment: @Noldor130884 Polluted water with some bacteria into it. Some beaches can contain bacterias even in sand, not only in water.

Answer (score 0):

Best place aviable to swimming there - common pools :-) .

In Moscow summmer people usualy go away from Moscow city ( more than 100-150 km) for beach on river. In city no beaches at all ( a really bad).